# How do I return relevant error messages to an end-user from ppm/cracklib when embedded in an OpenLDAP password policy?

Tags: ldap, openldap, cracklib

I'm deploying a new OpenLDAP server with a password policy that uses ppm as the pwdcheckmodule with cracklib enabled.  When a user authenticates, the only response they get back is from OpenLDAP "(-19) Password quality check failed." (or something very similar).  However, in the OpenLDAP log there are detailed messages that tell you which ppm check failed or why cracklib rejected the password.  I'm trying to get those messages back to the end user so that they have more detailed information about why the password check failed.

I'm currently using Oracle's DBMS_LDAP package for Oracle Internet Directory to change the password.  This is obviously not ideal and if there's another way to get these messages I can probably hack it together, but I can't seem to find a place to start.